# Using ajax-post within mocha test reporter fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mocha.js

i'm tyring to send my mocha test results with jquery post to my API. So I wrote a custom reporter:

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var $ = require('jquery');
module.exports = Reporter

function Reporter(runner) {
    mocha.reporters.Base.call(this, runner);
    var passes = 0;
    var failures = 0;

    runner.on('pass', function (test) {
        passes++;
    });

    runner.on('fail', function (test, err) {
        failures++;
    });

    runner.on('end', function () {
        data = {
            date: formatDate(new Date()),
            passed: passes,
            failed: failures
        }

       $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:8080/test/results",
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                console.log("sent");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("failed");
            }
        });

    });
}
```

I used `npm i jquery` and it added `"jquery": "^3.4.1"` into my package.json

But when I execute mocha tests, it throws an exception, that `$.ajax is not a function`. My research didn't find any helpful results. (And I don't use the slim-version of jquery)
Any idea what I did wrong? Or may I not use `$.ajax` for this?

Comment: Not sure why JQ isn't defined, it should be. However, your ajax usage is wrong. Read here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Aviad damn thanks, I knew something was wrong with my ajax request :D I corrected it. But still same error..

Comment: Try to remove the `npm_modules` directory and run `npm i` again. This is weird ...

Comment: @Aviad didn't change anything :(

Comment: Is there a way you can supply me with your code? I'll take a look (Github or equiv)

Comment: @Aviad yeah: https://github.com/matthiasburger/TestRepo . Thx :) - I uncommented the ajax thingy, added fetch for now. But I'd rather use ajax if this is possible

Comment: I've PRd you, have a look :)

Comment: I had to change it a bit again, but made it work with axios. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Initializing jQuery in Node vs in Browser

The problem seems to be with initializing jQuery in Node, which is different than initializing in browser.

Documentation of jQuery npm package, which you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), says as follows:

> For jQuery to work in Node, a window with a document is required.
>   Since no such window exists natively in Node, one can be mocked by
>   tools such as jsdom. This can be useful for testing purposes.

Instead of simply using below line:

```
var $ = require('jquery'); // Would work in browser
```

You should first mock DOM and after that initialize jQuery:

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```